# mySQL Query for summing counts in columns (date)

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, aggregate-functions

I have data in the following format:

id, count, date

I would like to get the data in the following format:

```
id|2017-09-01|2017-09-02|2017-09-03|2017-09-04|2017-09-05
--|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------
 1|     1    |     1    |     0    |     3    |     9
 2|     0    |     3    |     0    |     2    |    29
 3|     5    |     7    |     0    |     3    |     0
 4|     4    |     1    |     0    |     6    |     5
```

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display (pivots and missing data) in application code. Beyond that, there's not enough question here to warrant further attention.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not easy to be a beginner.

Comment: Yep. We've all been there.

Answer (score 0):

There's a basic trick to this that depends on this fact. In MySQL's dialect of sql, expressions like `datestamp = '2017-09-02'` have the value 1 or 0.

How can you apply that? Something like this:

```
SELECT id, 
       SUM(count * (datestamp = '2017-09-02')) "2017-09-02",
       SUM(count * (datestamp = '2017-09-03')) "2017-09-03"
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY id
```

Now you're going to ask how to make the column headings dependent on the content of your data.  *That* kind of pivoting is a notorious pain in the neck in MySQL. Do what @strawberry suggests.